# How to encode html and send via HTTP Post

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-post

I am trying send html elements via http post. How safely encode and decode html string? HtmlEncode doesn't help, because it doesn't encode & and it looks as new parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to URLEncode not HTMLEncode

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Please use HttpUtility.UrlEncode() for it

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the same way you would encode a query string.

```
string myPostVars = string.Format(
    "myHtml={0}&myInt={1}",
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("<div>This is my div</div>"),
    90210
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to pass anything via POST is to convert it into base64. Try
[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx).